# Add static text on Knockout.js data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to add static text to data-bind with something like the example below:

```html
<p data-bind="text:someProperty"></p>
```

I would like to add static text as below:

```html
<p data-bind="text:' + $' + someProperty"></p>
```

Comment: <p data-bind="text:' + $' + someProperty()"></p>

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment :) I added explanation below

Comment: How come the best answer is in the comment section?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you not put the static text inside the paragraph tag along with a span tag and data-bind on the span?

```
<p>text: <span data-bind="[whatever]" /></p>
```

Comment: Note that changes the output dom tree (which may or may not be ok). A <!-- ko --> tagless block would almost work, but I think you can't use text: in those.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an explanation of Imran's comment, above, which is a good answer

Your `text:` expression is normally wrapped in a ko.utils.unwrapObservable call:

```
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(someProperty)
```

but when you use a more complex expression, that implicit unwrapping doesn't work:

```
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(' + $' + someProperty) // won't find an observable; won't unwrap
```

So you must unwrap it yourself:

```
' + $' + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(someProperty) // good
```

or since you know it's an observable, you can simply use Imran's version:

```
' + $' + someProperty() // good, if someProperty is definitely an observable
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite late, (and new to Knockout) but here is another option I have used to add static text around an observable. In my case I wanted to add parentheses around a value that was chosen from a drop-down.

**javascript**

```
...
return function AppViewModel() {
    this.myOptionValues = ko.observableArray([
        { label: "Foo", value: "Bar" },
    ]);

    this.mySelectedValue = ko.observable();

    this.myValue = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.mySelectedValue() ? '(' + this.mySelectedValue().label + ')' : '';
    }, this);
};
...
```

**html**

```
<small data-bind="text: myValue"></small> // (Foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do would be to create a new Computed inside the viewModel and bind the text to that.
The computed concats the observable you need and the static text.
This is what it would look like

```
var myViewModel = {
   ...
   var self= this;
   self.myObservable = ko.observable('some value here');
   self.myComputed = ko.pureComputed(function(){
       return 'some text here' + self.myObservable() + 'you can use other text here';
   });
   ...
}
```

Then, in your HTML simply use the computed observable.

```
<p data-bind="text: myComputed"></p>
```

If you want flexibility, you can use parameters for the computed obs and pass them in the hmtl bind

```
self.myComputed2 = ko.pureComputed(function(param1) {
   return param1 + self.myObservable;
}
```

And in the html

```
<p data-bind="text: myComputed2("somestring")"></p>
```